# How count many fields (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the below and would like to a count of all bookings with a a count of all guests per week. There are 30 guest fields:

`locations`

```
| Field        | Type       |
| ------------ | ---------- |
| location     | text       |
| day_number   | int(11)    |
| month_number | int(11)    |
| year         | text       |
| week_number  | tinyint(4) |
| start        | datetime   |
| end          | datetime   |
| guest_1      | text       |
| guest_2      | text       |
| …            |            |
| guest_30     | text       |
```

I am using:

```
select locaton, count(*) AS `Number of bookings per week`, week_number, 
month_number, `month`
FROM locations
GROUP BY location, week_number;
```

That gets me:

```
| location     | ...Bookings | week_number | month_number | January  |
| ------------ | ----------- | ----------- | ------------ | -------- |
| Location One | 3           | 2           | 1            | January  |
| Location One | 5           | 3           | 1            | January  |
| Location One | 2           | 4           | 1            | January  |
| Location One | 2           | 5           | 2            | February |
| Location One | 5           | 6           | 2            | February |
| Location One | 1           | 7           | 2            | February |
| Location One | 3           | 8           | 2            | February |
```

There are many locations.

How can I combine **a count of guests** over the 30 guest fields for each week and location in my query?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: We can't work with a table structure, query and that output. We need better complete example data place it on db-fiddle.com.  We also need expected output.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com  ... Right now you only show us current ouput ... we need more

Comment: Also, do the right step and put the customers in an extra table instead of extra fields and make it a 1:N relation.

Comment: "Also, do the right step and put the customers in an extra table instead of extra fields and make it a 1:N relation" a many to many relation is a better approach @Cataklysim  you need the tables `locations` `geusts` and `locations_geusts` Assuming a geust can book multple times in multple location and multple weeks when he goes on vacation again

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @RaymondNijland. The data is an export from from a network connected device. I was trying to avoid changing the structure but I think that is the best way forward for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply count the guests for each combination and then sum up those counts

```
SELECT location,week_number,month_number,SUM(
(guest_1 <> "") +
(guest_2 <> "") +
(guest_3 <> "") +
....
(guest_30 <> "")
) AS num_guests
FROM locations
GROUP BY location,week_number,month_number
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much @ivo-gelov

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult because this table is not normalized.
In my opinion is this possible please re-create this solution and create new table **GUEST** with foreign key from **LOCATION**.

Next step is create subquery for example:

```
(you query) t1
having 30 = (select count(*) from GUEST where idlocation=t1.idlocation and year=t1.year, week_number=t1.week_number)
```

It will be more better resolve because in this situation you can add more guest without change logical table.
In your situation you always check every column separately.

Comment: I agree the data is not formatted correctly. I would like to run a query on this exported data without changing the structure. Upload a file, run a query, chart the response.